# REST - dealing with sub-resource access

Tags: rest, design-patterns, restful-url

I'm evaluating a possible REST API design and would like to ask for feedback or best practices on ways of dealing with nested resources.

Consider the following (JSON expressed) data model of a contrived book library that is analogous to the data I'm looking at. Please ignore the fact that a book can exist without a library, etc.

```
{ "library-name" : "foobar",
  "rows" : 
[
  {"row-id":"1", 
   "shelves": 
      [
        {"shelf-id":"1", 
            "books": 
              [
                {
                  "book":
                    {"book-name":"abc", "author":"someone"}
                }
              ]
         }
       ]
    }
 ]
}
```

Suppose then that the possible REST API design is:

```
/library (the root API URI)
/library/{library-name}/
/library/{library-name}/{row-id}
/library/{library-name}/{row-id}/{shelf-id}
/library/{library-name}/{row-id}/{shelf-id}/{book-name}
```

For POST operations the server would implement functionality to allow:

- Adding a new book, by performing a POST directly to /library/{library-name} encoding all the details of the book to a shelf, row, etc inside the nested data structure (like shown).
- GET operations would be allowed at each recourse level. The GET would return the fully nested data (eg returning as JSON data all the rows/shelves and books for a given library, etc).

There are some tradeoffs with the above:

- A given book resource can be accessed by several URIs. eg A POST to /library/{library-name} could be creating a book, as could a POST to /library/{library-name}/{row-id}/{shelf-id}. In such  indirect POST cases, the data rather than the URI identifies the actual target sub-resource. Is this RESTfuL?
- Allowing resources to be handled via their parent resource in POST/PUT operations is useful in bulk operations; saves on number of round trips. This benefit comes at the cost of a more elaborate data structure and handler code that the client and server have to deal with.

Comments? What am I'm missing here (I have not found many examples of the above, which makes me think that it's not a common design pattern)?

Comment: I'd call `library` `libraries` instead, since a `GET` on that resource would likely result in a list of (all) libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your description, you meant to expose ‘row’ and ‘shelf’ as the integral part of the URL, which is fine if that is your design intent. That is where your question comes in since if ‘row’ & ‘shelf’ are the integral part of the resources’ URL, then your should not do ‘so-call’ bulk POST/PUT/DELETE operations but that is fine with GET as long as the book-name is unique.

### I can see you have the follow business operations

**A) -Create a book at specific location**

```
HTTP POST /library/{lib-name}/{row-id}/{shelf-id}/{book-name}
Body: {json info for the book}
```

**B) -Get all books**

```
//in all library        
HTTP GET /library/

//in a specific library         
HTTP GET /library/{lib-name}/ 

//in a specific row         
HTTP GET /library/{lib-name}/{row-id}/

//in a specific row & shelf         
HTTP GET /library/{lib-name}/{row-id}/{shelf-id}/
```

**C) -Get specific book**

```
HTTP GET /library/{lib-name}/{row-id}/{shelf-id}/{book-name}

//If the book-name or ID is unique, you can access it from the toplevel
HTTP GET /library/books/{ book-name}
```

### If row & shelf are not important part of the URL, you will have

**A) -Create a book**

```
HTTP POST /library/{lib-name}/{book-name}
Body: {json info for the book including row & shelf}
```

**B) -Get all books**

```
//-in all library       
HTTP GET /library/

//-in a specific library        
HTTP GET /library/{lib-name}/
```

**C) -Get specific book**

```
//If the book-name or ID is unique, you can access it from the toplevel
HTTP GET /library/books/{ book-name}
```

### Updated

The decision here is from the application point of view, is {row}/{shelf} critical to be exposed to the client in the URL as a way to manage the **REST resources** or they are merely **attributes** of a book.

If {row} & {shelf} are also **REST resources** for client to manage or are used to identify the unique path to the resources (book in this case), it makes sense to have them as part of the URL and they should be subject to constraints under REST/HATEOAS. In order words, you should not use the complex body to include all the 'sub-resources' in your POST.

GET is more subtle.

It is straightforward for GET on URL

```
/library/{lib-name}/{row-id}/{shelf-id}/{book-name}
```

GET can be applied on '/library/{lib-name}/'. In this case, the body should contain some form of structured links to the underneath resources like

```
[
{/library/{lib-name}/{row-id}/{shelf-id}/{book-name}}, 
{/library/{lib-name}/{row-id}/{shelf-id}/{book-name}},
 ...]
```

But if they are just attributes, then they could be part of the complex body since they are not adding any value from the view of either Addressability nor Links and Connectedness.

REST concerns about the following (copied from [RESTful Web Services](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596529260))

- Addressability
- Statelessness
- Representations
- Links and Connectedness
- The Uniform Interface

Two great books on REST and have some discussions on the topic that you are interested in.

- [REST in Practice](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596805838.do)
- [Restful Web Services](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596529260)

Comment: Thanks! So what would be your opinion on a REST API that implements say: HTTP POST /library/{lib-name}/{row-id}/{shelf-id}/{book-name} With the complex body.  Essentially, is there something not-RESTful in deriving the target sub-resource from the data in POST operations or having sub-resource data returned in GET to the parent even when those sub-resources have a URI?  I'm thinking that at the very least this design does not follow HATEOAS style.

Comment: As updated, if row & shelf are REST resources or part the 'Addressability' of identifying the resources, then they should not be hidden in the body.

Comment: Thanks again! I have one more query about these sub-resources. I'm wondering how to deal with the following case: When a "new book" POST is attempted for /library/{lib-name}/{row-id}/{shelf-id}/{book-name}, one would want to check/amend the shelf capacity. There clearly is resource dependency here (book resource dependent on shelf resource, both being managed). In implementation terms how would one tackle this? E.g. Should the {book} handler call on {shelf} handler, and make a check/change to the shelf resource? Again, I wonder if such indirect resource modifications are RESTful.

Comment: This has nothing to do with REST and it is the backend processing.  But how to report back to the client need to be handled in a restful way. Like when about to create the book, the backend validates if shelf or even the info about the book is valid before creating the book.

If anything fails, backend will return HTTP error code for example ‘400/412’  with error more info.